# How do I assign a 3d numpy array of different sizes to each element of a numpy vector?

Tags: python, numpy

Here are the situations:

```
x.shape = (20,)

x1 = x [0,]
x2 = x [1,]
x3 = x [2,]
```

...

The shapes of x1, x2, x3 ... are all different.

For example,

```
x1.shape = (300, 400, 3)
x2.shape = (280, 520, 3)
x3.shape = (330, 400, 3)
```

I have a 3d numpy array of different sizes

I want to assign it to each element of vector called x.

What should I do?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. You should show an example.

Comment: In summary, I wanted to know how to assign a vector of x to a 3D array of different sizes for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Make your elements first, then create your `x` array from them

```
x = numpy.array([x1, x2, x3])
```

A modern `numpy` will automatically use `dtype=object` whereas in previous versions you had to add `dtype=object` explicitly.

This isn't really much different from using a plain Python `list` though:

```
x = [x1, x2, x3]
```